# Java RS 503 No server is available to handle this request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey, postman

I'm using Spring boot and rs Client. I want to send request post to a server by it responses me with 503. I used curl and i got the same thing but when I use Postman it works!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    config.register(JacksonFeature.class);
    config.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    config.register(ObjectMapper.class);

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
    Form forme = new Form();
    forme.param("j_username", LOGIN);
    forme.param("j_password", PASSWORD);

    WebTarget wt = client.target(URI).path(SERVICE_PATH);


    Response web = wt.request().post(Entity.entity(forme, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED));      
}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by replacing http with https